# Constrain function template parameters to callable return type (eg. lambda) with concepts, automatically deriving the type parameters

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Since `std::function` is slow, I'd like to have a templated function accepting a "getter" function / callable (eg. a lambda) and have the other types of the templated function automatically derived from the return type of this callable.

It's my first time using concepts so I know that maybe I'm doing something very wrong.

So far I've tried doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>

struct MyPoint
{
    glm::vec3 p;
    // ...
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::setS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    MyPoint>
MyGraph;

template<
    typename F,
    typename Ret,
    typename... Args>
concept Callable = std::invocable<F, Args...>
                && std::same_as<Ret, std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>;

template<typename TGraph,
         typename TFn,
         glm::length_t L,
         typename T,
         glm::qualifier Q,
         Callable<TFn, glm::vec<L, T, Q>, const typename TGraph::vertex_bundled &> TFnConcept>
std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec<L, T, Q>>>
convert_graph_to_contours(
    const TGraph &graph,
    const TFnConcept &fn_map)
{
    // this is just example code

    std::vector<size_t> components(boost::num_vertices(graph));
    const auto num_components = boost::connected_components(graph, components.data());
 
    std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec<L, T, Q>>> res;
    
    for(size_t i_comp = 0; i_comp < num_components; ++i_comp)
    {
        auto &vec = res.emplace_back();
        
        for(size_t i_vert = 0; i_vert < components.size(); ++i_vert)
        {
            if(components[i_vert] != i_comp)
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            vec.push_back(fn_map(graph[i_vert]));
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    MyGraph graph;
    
    {
        const auto vd1 = boost::add_vertex(MyPoint{ glm::vec3(0, 0, 0) }, graph);
        const auto vd2 = boost::add_vertex(MyPoint{ glm::vec3(10, 0, 0) }, graph);
        const auto vd3 = boost::add_vertex(MyPoint{ glm::vec3(0, 0, 10) }, graph);
        
        boost::add_edge(vd1, vd2, graph);
        boost::add_edge(vd2, vd3, graph);
        boost::add_edge(vd3, vd1, graph);
    }
    
    {
        const auto vd1 = boost::add_vertex(MyPoint{ glm::vec3(0, 50, 0) }, graph);
        const auto vd2 = boost::add_vertex(MyPoint{ glm::vec3(10, 50, 0) }, graph);
        const auto vd3 = boost::add_vertex(MyPoint{ glm::vec3(0, 50, 10) }, graph);
        
        boost::add_edge(vd1, vd2, graph);
        boost::add_edge(vd2, vd3, graph);
        boost::add_edge(vd3, vd1, graph);
    }
    
    const auto fn = [&](const MyGraph::vertex_bundled &vb)
    {
       return vb.p; // glm::vec3
    };

    //auto ctrs = convert_graph_to_contours(graph, fn);
    auto ctrs = convert_graph_to_contours<
        MyGraph, decltype(fn), 3, float, glm::defaultp>(graph, fn);
    
    // ctrs must be of type std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>>

    std::cout << ctrs.size() << " contours" << std::endl;
    
    for(const auto &ctr : ctrs)
    {
        std::cout << "--- CONTOUR ---" << std::endl;
        
        for(const auto &p : ctr)
        {
            std::cout
                << p.x << ", "
                << p.y << ", "
                << p.z
                << std::endl;
        }
        
        std::cout << "---------------" << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

but the compiler doesn't like the arguments saying:
`error C2672: 'convert_graph_to_contours': no matching overloaded function found`

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
What I'd like is to have the call to `convert_graph_to_contours` possible without having to write the full type parameters of the template like:

```
auto ctrs = convert_graph_to_contours<
        MyGraph, decltype(fn), 3, float, glm::defaultp>(graph, fn);
```

since the `3, float, glm::defaultp` type parameters should be derived from the return type of `fn`; `MyGraph` and `decltype(fn)` should, well, be derived from the `graph` and `fn` arguments respectively.

**EDIT 2:**
With `std::function` I could write `convert_graph_to_contours(graph, fn)` (without specifying any type parameters at call site).

```
template<typename TGraph,
         glm::length_t L,
         typename T,
         glm::qualifier Q>
std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec<L, T, Q>>>
convert_graph_to_contours(
    const TGraph &graph,
    const std::function<glm::vec<L, T, Q>(const typename TGraph::vertex_bundled &)> &fn_map)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

const std::function fn = [&](const MyGraph::vertex_bundled &vb)
{
    return vb.p; // glm::vec3
};

auto ctrs = convert_graph_to_contours(graph, fn);
```

**EDIT 3:**
As an extra thing (I'm sorry!), it would be great to keep access to the values of `L, T, Q` as well, since it may be useful to construct other types of `glm::vec`s with some of the template parameters changed, like transforming a 2D point to 3D `glm::vec<2, float, glm::defaultp>` to `glm::vec<2, float, glm::defaultp>` or to loop over the dimensions like this:

```
TResult p = ...;
for(size_t i = 0; i < L; ++i) 
{
    std::cout << p[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "*I'd like to have a templated function accepting a "getter" function (lambda)*" Why does it specifically need to be a lambda, rather than any callable object?

Comment: It doesn't, it was just my use case here... I will edit the title and question to make it clear. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What is `ConnGraph`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I've provided a reproducible example. Sadly, not a minimal one because I couldn't create one without making the code too trivial such that a `std::transform` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a concept to constrain a template type-parameter, the first type-parameter of the concept is implicitly substituted, and you don't need a separate parameter for that.

With some re-arranging of the order of the parameters, such that the undeduced ones come first, we get

```
template<glm::length_t L,
         typename T,
         glm::qualifier Q,
         typename TGraph,
         Callable<glm::vec<L, T, Q>, const typename TGraph::vertex_bundled &> TFn>
std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec<L, T, Q>>>
convert_graph_to_contours(
    const TGraph &graph,
    const TFn &fn_map)
```

[Which works with a modified call site](https://godbolt.org/z/1bqoffa6K)

```
auto ctrs = convert_graph_to_contours<3, float, glm::defaultp>(graph, fn);
```

If you want to deduce the template parameters to `glm::vec` from the function, you can't constrain the function's return type.

Instead, first add a trait that captures whether a type is what you are after, and stores the parameters for you to access later (if `glm::vec` doesn't already)

```
template <typename> struct is_glm_vec : std::false_type {};
template <glm::length_t L,
          typename T,
          glm::qualifier Q> 
struct is_glm_vec<glm::vec<L, T, Q>> : std::true_type {
    static constexpr glm::length_t length = L;
    static constexpr glm::qualifier qualifier = Q;
    using value_type = T;
};
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_glm_vec_v = is_glm_vec<T>::value;
template <typename T>
constexpr glm::length_t glm_vec_L = is_glm_vec<T>::length;
template <typename T>
constexpr glm::qualifier glm_vec_Q = is_glm_vec<T>::qualifier;
template <typename T>
using glm_vec_t = is_glm_vec<T>::value_type;
```

Then use the result type in a `requires` clause

```
template<typename TGraph,
         std::invocable<const typename TGraph::vertex_bundled &> TFn,
         typename TResult = std::invoke_result_t<TFn, const typename TGraph::vertex_bundled &>>
requires is_glm_vec_v<TResult>
std::vector<std::vector<TResult>>
convert_graph_to_contours(
    const TGraph &graph,
    const TFn &fn_map)
```

Which makes the call site [what you want](https://godbolt.org/z/YqvEMMxj4)

```
convert_graph_to_contours(graph, fn);
```

And the body of `convert_graph_to_contours` can access `L`, `T` and `Q` via `glm_vec_L<TResult>` etc.

Comment: Or if OP wants `TFn` to be the first template parameter for any reason, we could instead change the constraint from a template parameter to an explicit constraint: `template<typename Fn,` ...`> requires Callable<TFn, glm::`...`> std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec<L, T, Q>>> convert_graph_to_contours(`...

Comment: Thank you, also it seems moving TGraph to the end, before the Callable helps... But it seems it's not possible to write just `convert_graph_to_contours(graph, fn)`... Maybe I need to explicitly write it in the question but with `const std::function<glm::vec<L, T, Q>(const typename TGraph::vertex_bundled &)> &fn_map` the compiler is happy without any type parameter explicity typed at call site. 

@aschepler thank you as well, I don't really care about the order of type parameters but good to know.

EDIT: Updated the question.

Comment: @TesX in `convert_graph_to_contours(graph, fn)`, where do you supply `L`, `T` and `Q`? That's why I moved those to the front

Comment: @TesX if you want the template to deduce the `glm::vec<L, T, Q>` for you, that can't be part of the constraint on `Fn`

Comment: @Caleth when I was using `std::function`, the compiler was able to derive everything weirdly enough (tested with GCC, clang and MSVC): https://godbolt.org/z/4vd1WMaxG

EDIT: I just saw your new comment

Comment: @Caleth I need to test it tomorrow at work. It may work but in this way I don't have access to the value of `L` (and `T`) which I may need to loop over dimensions in the glm::vec (eg a 2D vs a 3D point) like this: `TResult p = ...; for(size_t i = 0; i < L; ++i) { std::cout << p[i] << std::endl; }`. Anyway, I'm going to mark your answer as solution after testing it better tomorrow since I feel I have too many requirements and I don't want to seem ungrateful, I don't know.

Comment: @TesX you can add (static) members to `is_glm_vec` to capture `L`, `M`, and `Q` if they aren't available from `glm_vec` already.